# Thread not exited after process/task completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Found problem in the code. It seem that the code or the thread(i think) is not properly closed. 
The WebDev.WebServer40.EXE still running and using all the memory of my computer. I can see the memory usage from task manager increasing even after i stopped the Visual Studio(stop debugging).
 I need to end task using task manager to stop the process. The code is executed whenever the page loaded, it suppose to terminate/close all the operation whenever the task completed but its not. How to solve the problem?? What should i add/remove??

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class liveRecording : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    //video codec
    AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter("MSVC");  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string streamingSource = "http://xxx.sample.com:85/snapshot.cgi";
        string login = "login";
        string password = "password";

        JPEGStream JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(streamingSource);
        JPEGSource.Login = login;
        JPEGSource.Password = password;
        JPEGSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        JPEGSource.Start();
    }

    public bool IsRecording = false;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    Queue<Bitmap> frames = new Queue<Bitmap>(); //Queue that store frames to be written by the recorder thread

    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) //event handler for NewFrame
    {
        //get frame from JPEGStream source
        //Bitmap image = eventArgs.Frame;
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone(); //get a copy of the Bitmap from the source

        width = image.Width;
        height = image.Height;

        if (IsRecording)
        {
            //enqueue the current frame to be encoded to a video file
            frames.Enqueue((Bitmap)image.Clone());
        }

        if (!IsRecording)
        {
            IsRecording = true;
            Thread th = new Thread(DoRecording);
            th.Start();
        }
    }

    private void DoRecording()
    {
        //writer.FrameRate = 5;
        string SavingPath = (Server.MapPath("~\\video\\")); 
        string VideoName = "ICS_" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd_hhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + ".avi";
        writer.Open(SavingPath + VideoName, width, height);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Seconds < 30)
        {
            if (frames.Count > 0)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = frames.Dequeue();
                writer.AddFrame(bmp);//add frames to AVI file
            }
        }
        writer.Close();//close
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to accept answers on your previous question.

Comment: If you leave it long enough does the task complete? I ask because detaching the debugger won't actually stop the process like it does in WinForms.

Comment: @NickW Never tried it. I always stop it via task manager when my computer starting to slowing down and lag a lot even the cursor movement is not smooth anymore. So, i think its not stopping.

Comment: You are streaming from `http://xxx.sample.com:85/snapshot.cgi`. Does this stream have end? If not, that may be why this isn't stopping. Also, does the `frames` queue ever get cleared? That could be where your memory is getting chewed up.

Comment: @NickW thank you so much. i never thought about the streaming source. Yes, its have no end. The stream seems to continue and that what cause the problem. i just need to stop the streaming after the task completed and the problem solved. 1 question, if some data still inside the queue and never make it to the `dequeu` process, is it stay there without removed automaticaly? or do i need to clean it manually?

Comment: Because you are maintaining a reference to it, anything in `frames` that does not get dequeued will stay in memory. However, once you stop the process it should get garbage collected.